# Displaying Arabic characters in VSFlexgrid

Tags: vb6, arabic, vsflexgrid

I have a VB 6.0 application in which one of the windows needs to display Arabic characters. When it used VSFlexgrid 7 it worked fine, but since upgrading to VSFlexgrid 8 it displays question marks and other "junk" characters. I have references to vsflex8.ocx, vsflex8l.ocx, vsflex8n.ocx and vsflex8u.ocx in the project. Is there something else I need to download, or a setting I need to set somewhere?

Comment: Never used it but I can "google."  Two of those OCXs are ANSI only and not Unicode-aware.  Maybe this was a change from the prior version?  Have you tried the vendor's support site (assuming you have a license)?

Comment: Have you set your computer regional settings "language for non-Unicode programs" to something that supports Arabic?

Comment: did you resolve it yet? actually, I am also facing the same issue.